# Angular 4: Router Outlet Management

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two main component

1. Login
2. Dashboard

In the "Dashboard component" have some child components. Do I need to keep two `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

How I manage with Router. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second `</router-outlet>` will be in dashboard.component.html

In route for dashboard give children property for child routes.

```
{
    path : 'dashboard',
    component : DashboardComponent,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'childPath',
        component: ChildComponent
     }
}
```